# How to remove first character up to a specific character in a string using bash scripting?

Tags: string, bash, scripting, character

For example, I have a string:

`HelloWorld: This is HelloWorld: another HelloWorld`

How do I get from the above string to just

`This is HelloWorld: another Helloworld`

There can also be whitespaces in the beginning of the full string, and basically I just want to remove all characters up to the first occurance of the first colon (":") in the string.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look at `${parameter#[word]}` in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus I searched up the use of the sed command for removing characters from strings and found out that using sed 's/[:].*//' actually removes everything AFTER the first occurence of the colon. However, I haven't found out how to modify this command to remove everything BEFORE the first occurence of the colon though.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
string="HelloWorld: This is HelloWorld: another HelloWorld"
```

With a POSIX shell (useful when the string is already in a variable):

```sh
echo "${string#*: }"
```

With sed:

```
echo "$string" | sed 's/^[^:]*: //'
```

Comment: Thanks! This works!